# Angular Jest or Jasmine Testing: How to Properly Spy/Mock a Static Object Called From Within a Tested Class?

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, jestjs, angular8

I have an AppConfigService that loads an object from a JSON file into a static settings variable that is part of the service.  Various components and/or services throughout the application reference the object with AppConfigService.settings., with a simple reference (no injection).  How can I test a service that is referencing this kind of construction?

For example

```
@Injectable()
export class SomeService {
someVariable;
  constructor() {
    // I can't get the test to not give me a TypeError: Cannot read property 'someSettingsVariable' of undefined on this line
    this.someVariable = AppConfigService.settings.someSettingsVariable;
  }
}
```

I have two projects, one using Jest and another Jasmine/Karma and I need to figure out the pattern of how to get the test to work in this construction.

I have tried things like:

```
const spy = spyOnProperty(SomeService, 'someVariable')
        .and.returnValue('someValue');
```

Example spec:

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { NgRedux } from '@angular-redux/store';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { DispatchHelper } from '../reducers/dispatch.helper';
import { ContributorActions } from '../actions/contributor.action';
import { MockDispatchHelper } from '../_mocks/DispatchHelperMock';
import { DiscrepancyService } from '../discrepancies/discrepancy.service';
import { DiscrepancyAPIService } from '../discrepancies/discrepancy-api.service';
import { DiscrepancyAPIServiceMock } from '../_mocks/DiscrepancyAPIServiceMock';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Guid } from 'guid-typescript';
import { getInitialUserAccountState } from '../functions/initial-states/user-account-initial-state.function';
import { LoggingService } from '../security/logging/logging.service';
import { MockLoggingService } from '../_mocks/LoggingServiceMock';

describe('discrepancyService', () => {

    let discrepancyService: DiscrepancyService;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [
                { provide: Injectable, useClass: Injectable },
                { provide: DispatchHelper, useClass: MockDispatchHelper },
                { provide: ContributorActions, useClass: ContributorActions },
                { provide: NgRedux, useClass: NgRedux },
                { provide: DiscrepancyService, useClass: DiscrepancyService },
                { provide: DiscrepancyAPIService, useClass: DiscrepancyAPIServiceMock },
                { provide: LoggingService, useClass: MockLoggingService },
            ]
        })
            .compileComponents();

        const userStateObservable = Observable.create(observer => {
            const userState = getInitialUserAccountState();
            userState.userId = Guid.parse('<guid>');
            userState.organization_id = Guid.parse('<guid>');
            observer.next(userState);
            console.log('built user state observable');
            observer.complete();
        });

        discrepancyService = TestBed.get(DiscrepancyService);
        const spy4 = spyOnProperty(discrepancyService, 'userState$', 'get').and.returnValue(userStateObservable);
    });


    // TODO: Fix this
    it('should create service and loadDiscrepancies', () => {
      // in this example, discrepancyService constructor sets the
      // value of a variable = ApiConfigService.settings.endPoint
      // ApiConfigService.settings is static; how do I "replace"
      // the value of endPoint in a call like this so I don't get
      // an error because ApiConfigService.settings is undefined
      // when called from a service in the test?
      const spy = spyOn(discrepancyService.dispatcher, 'dispatchPayload');
      discrepancyService.loadDiscrepancies();
      expect(spy.calls.count()).toEqual(1);
    });

});
```

karma.conf.js

```
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma'),
      require('karma-spec-reporter')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, '../coverage'),
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    customLaunchers: {
      ChromeDebug: {
        base: 'Chrome',
        flags: [ '--remote-debugging-port=9333','--disable-web-security' ]
      },
      ChromeHeadlessCI: {
        base: 'Chrome',
        flags: ['--no-sandbox', '--headless', '--watch=false'],
        browserDisconnectTolerance: 10,
        browserNoActivityTimeout: 10000,
        browserDisconnectTimeout: 5000,
        singleRun: false
      }
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml', 'spec'],
    port: 9876,
    host: 'localhost',
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['ChromeDebug', 'ChromeHeadlessCI'],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

Any assistance from testing gurus would be appreciated.

Comment: please share a little more of your spec file, if you include as well the configuration of the test bed, you might get help for the problem

Comment: Hi MapLion, please add some more information. What you tried should work but is someVariable really a property or just a variable member? If it is a static variable just change the value, instead of spying on it. There is nothing to spy on there.

Comment: Sorry, I'll do that.  It's not technically my project, but I'll try to get more info.  I thought I added the relevant pieces.

Comment: @AthanasiosKataras how do I "just change the value", maybe that's what I'm missing.  I generally don't know how to do this with something being called in another function that is being tested.

Comment: Let me know if any of the three works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three ways I can see about it

### Set the value directly

```
// TODO: Fix this
it('should create service and loadDiscrepancies', () => {
  // in this example, discrepancyService constructor sets the
  // value of a variable = ApiConfigService.settings.endPoint
  // ApiConfigService.settings is static; how do I "replace"
  // the value of endPoint in a call like this so I don't get
  // an error because ApiConfigService.settings is undefined
  // when called from a service in the test?
  AppConfigService.settings = { endpoint: 'http://endpoint' }
  const spy = spyOn(discrepancyService.dispatcher, 'dispatchPayload');
  discrepancyService.loadDiscrepancies();
  expect(spy.calls.count()).toEqual(1);
});
```

## Add a null check and a setter

```
@Injectable()
export class SomeService {
someVariable;
  constructor() {
    // I can't get the test to not give me a TypeError: Cannot read property 'someSettingsVariable' of undefined on this line
    if (AppConfigService && AppConfigService.settings) {
        this.someVariable = AppConfigService.settings.someSettingsVariable;
    }
  }
}

set endPoint(value) {
    this.someVariable = value
}
```

## Hide the static implementation behind a service

This for me is by far the best solution. Instead of going with a static implementation, create a single instance service that can be spied upon easily. This is not only a problem for you as you can imagine, but a problem for all OOP languages where the static implementations are avoid.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ConfigService {
  private endpoint: string;
  constructor() { }
  get endPoint(): string {
      return this.endPoint;
  }
}
```

Full example for runtime angular configuration [here](https://davembush.github.io/where-to-store-angular-configurations/)

Comment: So you recommend just making it a Singleton and doing away with the static implementation altogether -- is that what you mean by the third option?  Setting the value directly did not work for me and I don't really want to go through and add a null check and setter for everything.

Comment: Yeap. Create the Configuration Service. I have added some example code and a reference of a full solution.

Comment: So, after much experimentation and trial and error (and none of your suggestions working), I discovered my underlying issue was a race condition as described in this thread: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23279  Note that this also includes the link you gave, which seems like it should work, but it doesn't under my circumstances.  I reworked following the last example in the thread and also following this: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers  Ultimately, I did away with the static variables and that led to my tests working again. I'll mark this as accepted.